# Why can ADB start private components?

Tags: android, android-intent, adb

I understand that [ADB](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) is a powerful tool for development and testing purposes. But, I quite don't understand that how ADB can even start private components within my app that are not exported. For example, the following command shows how ADB can start an Activity within my app via explicit intent:

```
 adb shell am start -n "<package_name>/.view.MyActivity"
```

MyActivity is only reachable through an explicit intent. In other words, there's no intent-filter tag defined for MyActivity in the manifest XML. On the other hand, I noticed that if start to launch a Activity which is public (meaning there's an intent-filter) and secured through a custom permission, ADB also can't start it and I get SecurityException (because ADB did't claim the permission?).